# How to integrate php code with json for sending email using php json

Tags: php, angularjs, json

Hi actually I am new to json as I implemented the code for sending Emails in php now I need to integrate with json can anyone help me regrading this? Thanks In Advance.

**This is my code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$inputStream = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($inputStream);
$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));
$username = $data->username;
$email = $data->email;
$password = $data->password;
$confirmpassword = $data->confirmpassword;
$mobileno = $data->mobileno;
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "accou", "accountant") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("accountant", $connection);
    $query = mysql_query("insert into register(username,email, password, repassword,mobile,confirm_code) values ('$username','$email', '$password' , '$confirmpassword', '$mobileno','$confirm_code')");
    if ($query) {
            $to = $_POST['email'];
        $from .= 'mail@gmail.com' . "\r\n\r\n";
        $subject="Your confirmation link here";
        $message.="Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
                $message.="http://web.com/accountant/controller/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";        
        $success = mail($to, $subject, $message);           
        $successJson='{"success":"We have sent a verification email ' .
            'to your email id '.$email.', please check your ' .
            'Inbox and verify your email in order to proceed further."}';
        print_r($successJson);  
    }else{
        $failureJson='{"error":"We are encountering some issue. Please try after some time."}';
        print_r($failureJson);  
    }

 ?>
```

Actually the data is inserted into the database but the email sending is not working can any one help me this?

Comment: Hi can anyone help me this please

Comment: Have you setup a mail server for the php?

Comment: Ya if i use only php without integrating with json it is working fine but how to do with json

Comment: Anyone knows regarding this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the json string yourself, why not encode array into json.

$jsonObj = array("success" => "success text");
print_r(json_encode($jsonObj));